# Render all newlines and maybe also spaces in a contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

I have a contenteditable div which is serving as a rich text box. The problem I have is that I need to insert text which can contain several consecutive spaces or newlines. I need to preserve all of this faithfully and not have it be mangled by the browser. I've tried to insert an extra break to have that as my "trailing" break, or even to insert the text inside `<pre>`, whose sole effect was to make the text look like shit in addition to not preserving my consecutive new lines.

How can I make the browser stop mangling my text and just render the text that I tell it to render.

Just to clarify, by the above, I mean that the text "\n\n", on it's own, is a frequent insertion.

The text is inserted through JavaScript and is not typed by the user. It's received from the server- think chat message, for example. I'm going to strip down my code now and see what's the smallest example I can make if the current answers do not solve.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/46Lqy1pv/

When you click "New Paragraph" for the first time, only one line is added to the textbox rendered, but I *must* render both newlines.

Comment: Would you be able to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`? I haven't tried this myself it's just the first thought that popped into my head.

Comment: @Dale: No idea, I'm primarily concerned with new lines right now. I changed my title to be more upfront about this.

Comment: From what I can tell having just thrown a test together; multiple new lines are already converted into multiple br tags, at least in firefox they are.

Comment: There’s the problem that browsers convert newlines to markup, e.g. `<br>` tags, in different ways. Do you want that replaced by newlines?

Comment: I converted the newlines to markup myself with a split('\n'), a little process on each line, then join('<br>'). The problem is that with multiple consecutive breaks, they are not rendered, even in a <pre>.

Comment: Please show your code and clarify whether you are referring to content entered by the user or added entirely with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome have a different behaviour when rendering an empty contenteditable div.

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]

(Left: Firefox 35, Right: Chrome 40)

Firefox hides the div if it's empty, and Chrome let the user edit it by adjusting his height to one line.

When you click the "New Paragraph" button, both browsers add two `<br>` in the `<div>`, and the result will be the same:

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]

This is because Chrome removes the default style it applied before to the empty contenteditable div, since it's not empty anymore.

---

One possible solution is to add a `<br>` tag in your contenteditable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="textdiv"><br/></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szkhe1b7/

Firefox users will be able to edit the div, and Chrome users will get two new lines when "New Paragraph" is clicked.

Comment: That is informative, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation. I only need to target Chrome. I did try adding an additional break before adding the ones I wanted, which should in this theory solve the problem, but it did not have much effect.

Comment: @Puppy: I've edited the answer with a fiddle which seems to correct the problem.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem in the fiddle, and therefore I am going to accept your answer. I wondered if you had any suggestions as for how this could work if the div is created empty, and sometimes other libraries will set the content of the div with no respect for my need for this spare newline- in other words, how to determine if I need to add the additional newline given just the current state of the div.

Answer (score 3):

See *white-space* css rules :

```
p {
     white-space:pre-line;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New",Courier,mono;
}

p.pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p class="pre">
With :
  /\_/\
=( °w° )=
  )   (  //
 (__ __)//
</p>
<p>
Without :
  /\_/\
=( °w° )=
  )   (  //
 (__ __)//
</p>
```

Comment: New lines entered into a content editable element are already converted into br tags though, what would happen then?

Comment: br tag add new line. See documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: I did not have any success with this answer. Going to stick up a fiddle now.

Comment: The next time, begin by make a fiddle.

Comment: @HorsSujet I know what br tags do thanks lol, I mean what would happen using css white-space:pre-line + br tags!